# Eclipse cannot infer correct type from java 8 stream

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-8, java-stream

The following code works fine in all online java compilers but eclipse throws compiler error. Is it a bug in eclipse or am I missing some setting somewhere? A simple fix to silence eclipse? online: https://ideone.com/l0bbhz. *Note*: This is a simplified cooked-up example to just point to the problem. I understand `flatMap` is not necessary in this case. In the actual case, I really need `flatMap`

```
package dummy;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class LearnJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] sa = {"ne", "two", "three"};
        List<String> l = Arrays.stream(sa)
                .flatMap(s -> Collections.singleton(s).stream().map(c -> c.toUpperCase()))
                .collect(toList());
        System.out.println(l.get(0));
    }

}
```

Error in eclipse console.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<String>

    at dummy.LearnJava.main(LearnJava.java:13)
```

My eclipse version:

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
>   Build id: 20150219-0600

---

**Update**: I went with this minor workaround. It works without major refactoring!

```
.flatMap(s -> Collections.singleton(s).stream().map(c -> c.toUpperCase()))
```

To

```
.<String>flatMap(s -> Collections.singleton(s).stream().map(c -> c.toUpperCase()))
```

Comment: I dont know which kind of eclipse you are using but everything works with me here on eclipse Neon. I think you might have some settings

Comment: Eclipse does not use the standard Java compiler that ships with the Oracle JDK; it appears Eclipse's compiler has had [some type inference problems](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434483) in the past, so make sure you're using an up-to-date version

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. I am using Eclipse Mars.2 and JDK 1.8.0_92.

Comment: As @oldrinb said there might be that you dont have the latest JDK because i dont have this error on eclipse Neon. please check and update your JDK and try again

Comment: @SeekAddo this is not a problem of the JDK. My JDK is up-to-date and the program compiles fine on console. This is a problem with Eclipse.

Comment: you need to make sure that your "source compatibility" part of the Java Compiler dialog has to be 1.8 and the .class. if it doesnt work try to install the support file for Luna, You can get all the information here in the [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler)

Comment: @balki jsyk you should replace `flatMap` and `Collections.singleton(s).stream().map(c -> c.toUpperCase())` with `map` and `s.toUpperCase()`--this shouldn't make a difference re: type inference on `toList`

Comment: as @oldrinb mentioned: the troubling part for Eclipse is the call to `flatMap(...)`. Writing `[...].<String>flatMap(...)` instead of `[...].flatMap(...)` makes Eclipse resolve the rest of the types just fine.

Comment: @SeekAddo Source compatibility already set to 1.8. Installed the support file too. Still same error

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks. Adding <String> before flatMap worked fine. I hope that is harmless

Comment: Eclipse was quite late to adopt to streams and lambdas and is sometimes still struggeling today. Don't try this with old Luna. In my installation ( Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600) your code works fine.

Comment: Well, replacing the entire `flatMap` step with a simple `.map(String::toUpperCase)` works too. As a side note, even if you stick to `flatMap`, the term `Collections.singleton(s).stream()` is an unnecessarily verbose variant of `Stream.of(s)`. @mtj: unfortunately, while Mars solves this problem, it introduces new type inference bugs.

Comment: @Holger Updated 'Note' to be more clear. Thanks for the `Stream.of` tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse compiler is not perfect. Sometimes you'll hit issues such as [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/508834). For example, there are currently two bugs open related to `flatMap` and type interference - [482664](https://bugs.eclipse.org/482664) and [502158](https://bugs.eclipse.org/502158).

If you believe the code is legit, which is strongly the case when javac compiles it without issues, then you should open a bug and post a snippet there in order to let them know about it. This helps improving the compiler.

Comment: Nearly a year later, this translates to: "Upgrade Eclipse!"

Comment: @Stewart funny, because even when I used the most recent version of Eclipse (Oxygen) I still got this error...